# How can I control my WIFI router configuration in an Android app without using webview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, equation-solving, wifimanager

I want to create An android App to control WIFI router configuration such as change WIFI password , name change limited device and more .
but without used webview
I do not know what should.
please help me.

I Wanna Some one to guide me to right way.